# Django Model Form not appearing in admin

Tags: python, django

I've got a feedback app in django and it all seems to work fine, no errors i can submit the form and it all seems to work, however i have my model registered into my admin however when i submit the form i doesn't appear in my admin. Sorry if this is very basic i just cant get my head around it please help.

in my models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

which i then pass through to forms.py

```
class FeedbackModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ["email", "message"]
```

and my view is

```
def feedbackform(request):
    form = FeedbackModelForm(request.Post or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, "feedback.html", {"form": form})
```

now in my html looks like this

```
{% block content %}

<div id="feedback">
    <div id="feedback-form" style='display:none;' class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 panel panel-default">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ form }}" class="form panel-body" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="email" autofocus placeholder="Your e-mail" type="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" required placeholder="Please write your feedback here..." rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="feedback-tab">Feedback</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and in my admin

```
from .models import Feedback
from .forms import FeedbackModelForm

class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FeedbackModelForm
admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)
```

Comment: Did you know Django can render your forms for you? See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template. The reason I suggest that is that Django form fields have error attributes that will be rendered automatically if you use the default rendering. It is possible an error in form validation is occuring.

Comment: Hi thank you, is this the only option? as the currently the feedback tab is in the corner and im not sure the django form will fit very well.

Comment: You can manually render the error fields, I just suggested what I did as I thought it might be easier. You could also just `print(form.errors)` in your view after the `if form.is_valid():` block just to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @caldf: you have passed the {{ form  }} as the action attribute, which is completely wrong. Put it inside a div as {{ form.as_p }} that will work for you.

Comment: @Prateek You should post that as an answer. That looks like it will solve the problem. Probably also mention the `url` tag that should replace the action. I can't believe that I missed that.

Comment: @caldf: I have posted it as an answer please check and if useful mark it as correct answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed the

```
{{ form }}
```

as the action attribute, which is completely wrong. Put it inside a div as

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

that will work for you.

And in the action attribute pass a url in the form of

```
{% url 'home_page_example' %}
```

if you wanted to remain in the same page and redirect via view
you can write

```
action = "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Show us how did you register your model in the admin.

Make sure that you explicit config the form, like this

```
class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = FeedbackModelForm
admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment but im afraid i i tried what you suggested but i didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should return email or message in `def __unicode__(self):`, not title.

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check if the view is currently saving your Feedback.

Try inspecting the DB or in a manage.py shell check if `len(Feedback.objects.all())` change when you submit a Feedback in your view.

Also, I recommend you to change the email field to an `EmailField` and use the `FormView` class based view.